# Sending attachment via Web Service using java script

Tags: javascript, web-services, lotus-domino

I want to attach PDF file to Domino/Notes document using Web service. Currently i have done saving the Notes document by web service using java script. The problem is the sending PDF file to domino server.

How to achieve this?

Comment: please have time to accept answers of your previously asked questions. This way people will be encouraged to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the attachment base64 encoded, as provided for by the XSD_BASE64BINARY class that is defined in the lsxsd.lss file. See [Practical Web services in IBM Lotus Domino 7: Writing complex Web services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/web-services3/#N102C6) for an example on how to deal with attachments.